# how to split specific words in text file using powershell

Tags: file, powershell, split, cpu-word

I have an input text file content for example:

```
123 811SATELITE 09849302 12345567<br/>
123 811SATELITE 09849302 12345567<br/>
123 SATELITE 09849302 12345567
```

I want the output text file will be:

```
123 811 SATELITE 09849302 12345567<br/>
123 811 SATELITE 09849302 12345567<br/>
123 SATELITE 09849302 12345567
```

Is it possible to do this using powershell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know exactly what you want to split, you can use simple replace:

```
(Get-Content c:\temp\file.txt).replace('811SATELITE', '811 SATELITE') | Set-Content c:\temp\file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace in ps prompt and split what you want using regular expressions. Example below to add space after digits if "SATELITE" is next.

`'123 811SATELITE 09849302 12345567' -replace "(\d+)(SATELITE)",'$1 $2'`